# C++11 for development of cross platform (mobile/desktop) library

Tags: android, ios, windows, c++11, cross-platform

Looks like it's a very common practice to use C++03 for application's backend and implement frontend with native platform tools. There are a lot of articles how to put together: Java and C++ for Android; Objective C and C++ for iOS; .Net and C++ for Windows. And C++11 makes language more comfortable for development and it should make C++ number one choice in the real cross platform development.

But is C++11 supported by all main platforms already (like C++03)?

2 yeas ago I could definitely say - quality of C++11 is different on all major platforms, so better use C++03. But how about now 2015?

What I need from modern compilers to support in C++11:

1. General language tools like `nullptr`, `auto`, move semantics, `constexpr`, lambda functions, etc.
2. C++11 standard library with: `shared_ptr`, threads, `chrono`, new STL containers like `array` and hash tables.

What compilers I have to use:

1. clang (for iOS 7 and upper)
2. gcc for linux and newest Android versions
3. MSVC 2010 (I know it is very old but many our projects still use it).

Can I use C++11 for cross platform development in 2015 with those requirements?

Comment: Working now on a library with cross platform support (iOS -clang \ Windows - msvc \ LInux - clang too) with C++11. Nearly all features you listed work well (unsure about chrono\modern STL containers, do not use'em). One of the problems met so far is filesystem traversing (third-party library required like boost::filesystem or something like that)

Comment: But I'd consider a newer version of VS, here's a [list of supported feaures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx) in msvc2010

Comment: Thanks. But we choose to use older standard for better platforms support.